# Black screen when loading google web store on chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, linux-mint, reboot

pc screen goes black and have to reboot when selecting web store on chrome browser 39.0.2171.19 beta and Linux 17 mint, other pages are ok, only has happens when loading web store (every Time) and you tube once

Comment: Beta software. Have you looked in the chrome bug list?

Answer (score 0):

The link APPS on the browser bar causes the issue. was able to access through link to APPS in the GMail window